# How to write a function using for and if

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code for calculating the number of factors for an arbitrary integer number but unfortunately when I run that I receive a false answer

I have tried for loop without defining function in this case and I got the result.Contrary to that, when I define a function I can't see the proper result

```
r = 0
def factor(a):
    global r
    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
        r += 1
        return r

a = int(input())
factor(a)
```

for example `18` has `6` factors but I receive just `1`.

Comment: Indenting is important in python. Your `if` block is not properly indented.  Also your `return` is to far indented.

Comment: Python is unusual in this regard... does that issue count as "simple typographical error"? I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please check the indentation of your code?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. And don't use a global variable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use print to check your code. Indentation in Python matters. Also, global is not needed.

```
def factor(a):
    r = 0
    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
            print('i', i)
            r += 1
    return r

a = int(input())
print(factor(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an indentation problem: the function should only return after the loop has finished iterating.

```
r = 0
def factor(a):
    global r
    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        if a % i == 0:
            r += 1
    return r

a = 18   # int(input())
factor(a)
```

**output:**

```
6
```